# Initializing a subclass of UITextField in swift

Tags: ios, swift, initialization, uitextfield, subclass

So I've set up a UITextField that works correctly, but when trying to standardize the control so it can be reused in other views, I can't seem to initialize it/have it work the same way it does as a plain UITextField.

The variable is declared as

```
@IBOutlet weak var searchTextField: SearchTextField!
```

And then initialized and the delegate is set:

```
self.searchTextField = SearchTextField()
self.searchTextField.delegate = self
```

But I get EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION when trying to set the delegate.  I've been taking out and adding various init methods to the subclass, my current version has 3 which is probably overkill, but they stop the compiler from complaining:

```
import Foundation

class SearchTextField : UITextField
{
    override init()
    {
        super.init()
    }

    override init(frame:CGRect)
    {
        super.init(frame:frame)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    func setPlaceholderText()
    {
        let searchIconCharacter: Character = "\u{1F50D}"
        let searchFieldPlaceholder: String = "\(searchIconCharacter) Where to?"
        self.placeholder = searchFieldPlaceholder
    }
}
```

I'm sure my swift syntax is terrible so anything else I should correct let me know.  Something is causing the SearchTextField to not be set up, it's still nil after being initialized?  Is it something to do with it being a weak IBOutlet?

Comment: Does `self` conform to `UITextFieldDelegate`? (Like `class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate`)

Comment: Yes, exactly like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there were multiple problems with my horrible code, the ultimate solution was changing the UITextField to SearchTextField in the storyboard.  Aaron was also right that I was overwriting the instance created by the storyboard incorrectly, of course.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're initializing this in code, not interface builder, change your declaration from:

```
@IBOutlet weak var searchTextField: SearchTextField!
```

to

```
var searchTextField = SearchTextField()
```

This will stop your view from getting deallocated.

Comment: It is actually created on the storyboard, and all of the other IBOutlets in this class are weak as well...If I take out the self.searchTextField = SearchTextField() then I do have an object, but the address is listed as "some" which is confusing.  More precisely, I get this when I 'po self.searchTextField':   `Some
 {
  UIKit.UITextField = {
    UIKit.UIControl = {
      UIKit.UIView = {
        UIKit.UIResponder = {
          ObjectiveC.NSObject = {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`

Comment: That's normal. That's because it's an optional. `self.searchTextField = SearchTextField()` is overwriting your other text field with a new instance. Sounds like you don't want that.

Comment: I've taken it out, and agree it's probably not wanted, but it doesn't change much.  Setting the delegate seems to work, but the very next line then has a bad access error.  That line is `self.searchTextField.setPlaceholderText()` which seems fine to me...

Comment: Please post your whole method and the complete stack trace. I can't reproduce the issue using what you've posted.

Comment: Playing around with a bit longer, I found the problem was actually in IB - the textfield on the storyboard was still UITextField, instead of SearchTextField, so it couldn't respond to setPlaceholderText, my method.  Sorry for all the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

to

```
required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```